# create_category_channel() with position of 0 creates channel at bottom

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to create a category channel at the very top of the channels list in the discord server

```
c_channel = await guild.create_category_channel('Server Stats', position=0)
```

according to the [discord py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create%20channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) the position starts at 0

why is the category channel created at the very bottom of the channel list?

Comment: Category are from bottom, pos=0 is bottom. I think I'm right.
Why not just get the length of categories and pass it into the position?

Comment: I tried passing position as 1 but it put the category second from the top instead of second from the bottom. That wouldn't make sense if position 0 is at the bottom. I ended up just editing the channel after it was created and position 0 put it at the top.

Comment: That's good. Glad you fixed it.